# the_excerpt() or get_the_excerpt with shortcode escape

Tags: excerpt

I have few posts which have a dropcap shortcode wrapped around the first character like so:

```
[dropcap]T[/dropcap]his is a dropcap.
```

The replacement for this shortcode yields:

```
<span class="dropcap">T</span>his is a dropcap.
```

However, when I call the_excerpt() or get_the_excerpt() on these posts, its returning:

```
"his is a dropcap".
```

I need it to return "This is a dropcap" as if no shortcode exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make WordPress execute your shortcode in the excerpt by hooking into `get_the_excerpt` filter and overwriting the default `wp_trim_excerpt` function, which is responsible of stripping the shortcode tags from the excerpt as pointed by Chip:

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'do_my_shortcode_in_excerpt');
function do_my_shortcode_in_excerpt($excerpt) {
    return do_shortcode(wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 55));
}
```

This is applied to both `the_excerpt()` and `get_the_excerpt()` outputs. If you want to apply it only for `the_excerpt()` output, hook to `the_excerpt` filter:

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_my_shortcode_in_excerpt');
function do_my_shortcode_in_excerpt($excerpt) {
    return do_shortcode(wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 55));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [**`the_excerpt()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) function doesn't parse shortcodes. WordPress actually strips the entire shortcode from the excerpt. Since the "T" is wrapped in a shortcode, it doesn't get output by `the_excerpt()`.

The easiest solution is probably to create a *custom* excerpt, via the Post Excerpt meta box on the Edit Post screen, for posts in which you use the Dropcap shortcode.

The better solution is probably to ditch a shortcode that exists solely to do something that can reliably be done using nothing more than CSS rules.